# Android 2.3.6: Title bar scrolls out of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

For now I working on code editor for android. The problem is when keyboard is appeares the title bar scrolls out of device screen.[image]

XML: `<RelativeLayout> <EditText /> </RelativeLayout>`

Comment: Can you post the whole layout code?

Comment: @Passos I tryed. But StackOverflow says that it too much code in question. `<RelativeLayout> <EditText /> </RelativeLayout>`

Comment: Past it somewhere (like in gist) and link here